# Couldn't compile yew

Tags: rust-cargo, yew

I am using [build a sample app](https://yew.rs/docs/getting-started/build-a-sample-app) from yew docs. I don't know why this app throw this error.

[image]

this is yew version in Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }
```

this is code in main.rs

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
let counter = use_state(|| 0);
let onclick = {
    let counter = counter.clone();
    move |_| {
        let value = *counter + 1;
        counter.set(value);
    }
};

html! {
    <div>
        <button {onclick}>{ "+1" }</button>
        <p>{ *counter }</p>
    </div>
}
}

fn main() {
  yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Yew App</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your screenshot doesn't quite match the example you posted here (there's no UseStateHandle, etc) but assuming that's not an issue I took a quick look at

- `~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/yew-0.20.0/src/lib.rs` on my system and
- https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/master/packages/yew/src/lib.rs on github

Neither of those has a `pub(crate) fn start_app() -> {` at line 348.  They only have 346 lines.

I suspect something's wrong with your cargo registry.
You should take a closer look at the files on your system to confirm this.

I don't know if there's a way to correct this but if I were to encounter this condition I would

- rename my `~/.cargo/registry` to something like `~/.cargo/registry.bak`

and then try again.
If that fixed the problem I'd remove the `~/.cargo/registry.bak`. If not I'd put it back.

Comment: rename `~/.cargo/registry` to `~/.cargo/registry.bak` works fine. Could you tell me why rename file work? Is it because of file name conflict?

Comment: That directory is where `cargo` keeps crates you download (like the corrupted `yew-0.20.0` in this case). Over time it [can get large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063818/why-is-the-cargo-directory-so-big). Renaming the directory makes `cargo` behave as if it's not there.  I only suggested renaming it instead of deleting it in case you were experiencing some other problem and/or wanted to keep the corrupted one around for further investigation.  Otherwise you can remove it to reclaim space on your system.